# How do I take apart a wooden pallet without cracking the wood?

Tags: wood

I'm trying to save the wood from some wooden pallets and have been unsuccessful.  I have been hammering close to where the nails are and then pry the nails out; however, before the wood comes out far enough to remove the nails it usually snaps in half.  Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: pallets are built from junk hardwood with tons of flaws.  why are you even bothering?  Cut the boards at the ends before the nails and salvage the rest.

Comment: Junk is sometimes another's riches. There are folks that have built whole small buildings entirely from pallets!!

Comment: Pallets are great for a lot of projects, but in my worldview, they're better if you can use them whole. If you are disassembling them, you should buy lumber instead.

Answer (score 8):

They make several styles of tools that are made specifically for getting nails out. One tool called a "cats paw" looks like the picture below. (You may find similar tool under other localized names). A hammer is used to pound the hooked end in under the nail head so that it can then be levered out.

[image]

Another type of nail puller is also very effective in that the tool is used by itself without a need for a separate hammer. The handle on this type of nail puller is used to slide up and pound dowwards to embed the jaws around the nail head. Pulling sideways in the direction of the "foot" forces the jaws to clamp tightly on the nail and pull it out.

[image]

Comment: Those are good tools for regular nails, but for coated wire nails commonly used in pallets, the cats' paw will tear off the head, and the jaws on the slide hammer puller will cut the shank.

Comment: I have used a nail Jack , second photo to remove the twisted square shank nails on oak pallets , yes the wood is low quality I would not waste time on soft wood but oak can be run through a planer and still has lots of usage.

Answer (score 4):

For the first few corners you need to cut the nails in half once you have them out a little. Dremel tool with a diamond bit might work.  If you pull them out too much they do crack.

Comment: I'd use a recip with a 12" bi-metal or carbide blade

Comment: I think it is funny that my answer is down voted when I have done this before and many people own a dremel or something that could cut a nail.  But how many people (cheap enough to want to keep a crate) own a cat's paw... whatever.  And I don't understand how the cat's paw or any other nail puller won't damage the wood.

Comment: I +1 to counter the anonymous downvote.  A downvote without a comment does not follow our site suggestions.  I think a -1 should be reserved for BAD, dangerous, misleading answers, which is why its incumbent to comment.

Comment: I don't mind the down vote if my suggestion is either unsafe, doesn't work, or there is a much better solution.  I just thought it was odd that a solution that I have tried and does not work got a bunch of votes.  If you pry the nails out too far the wood will crack.  @Herr both of your cutting suggestions are valid and maybe better than mine.  Just threw out what I have done from experience.  I use the pallet boards for the walls of my shed... 2-3 more pallets and I am done.

Comment: A nail Jack may start the pull and if it quits moving will cut the nail you can then get another bite or use a flat bar or wonder bar to pry it loose.

Answer (score 3):

I usually collect pallets from the street, because my parents won't buy me wood for me making stuff for my stuff, they only buy it when I'm making their stuff. For the first time I did it, it was so difficult and hard work, I had a whole day of sour muscle but 80%of the hard wood from the pallets had snapped. I recalled the memory that I did it, and found out maybe I should use a chisel and hammer it in between the two timber that are nailed together, and using the pole principle to pull them apart, then use a the end bit of the hammer and use the same pole principle to pull it out. After taking down dozens of pallets, I also had an experience about pull each nail out a bit each time so the timber won't bend and therefore snap. Never use a hammer to try hammer it out, you will damage the timber and snap it as well. Hammer the chisel in and pull it apart.
here's some example of the timber I took down:
[image: these are the timber I took down and I filled the nail holes and sanded it with P40]

[image: from the front]
[image: I use them to make some boxes for my stuff]

Comment: Those look similar to much of the free pallets I have reclaimed, time is cheap when you don't have a job.

Answer (score 1):

I was very successful with simply cutting a notch in a 1x6. This notch would be for the pallet planks on the bottom side of your pallet so make sure it's big enough to span the largest width plank. Then I would take this 1x6 and set it in between the planks and next to the "2x4" that all the planks are nailed to. This would raise the pallet off the ground +- 1" . I would then take a minisledge and pound down on the pallet. This would create incremental moments of pressure that pulled the planks apart from the 2x4. I would then move my 1x6 to the middle and opposite end section. This loosened 95% of my planks without splitting (which I commonly have happen with just a hammer and crowbar) Then I would use a crowbar to pull on the nail only. It might sound complicated but it's not the only hard part was the constant sound from hammering. [image]

Comment: This seems to resemble the approach demonstrated on this YouTube video: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/68993/81954

Answer (score 0):

I used a FEIN saw with metal cutting blade and then a punch attached to a palm air hammer and that took out nails real fast. Very fast work taking apart a pallet no damage except where the  nails were pushed back through on some that were sunken in the wood.

Comment: FEIN appears to be a company, not a type of saw.  Could you please be more specific about the type of saw you used?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can use specialized equipment like Dan Padilla suggests, but I will assume you don't have such equipment.

You need to lever across both sides of the nail which is hard to do with a hammer. Use a nail puller and wedge it into the crack where the plank is nailed to the joist.

If that isn't working for you, get a hacksaw and cut in the seam where the two pieces of wood meet. After they are apart use a nail set (a small metal pin) to knock out the nail.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to create a gap, a space, by whatever means, between the planks and the structural 2x4s (which planks are nailed to)- - such that you can insert a metal cutting saw blade (hack saw, or reciprocating power saw) then you can carefully cut the nails, closer to the underside of the planks, leaving a small headless nail "stem" on the surface of the 2x4.

Then, use ViceGrip pliers to carefully pullout the remaining embedded nail.  Clamp the nail "stem" tight enough such that the pliers don't over-compress the metal stem, and cause it to weaken and snap off; yet firmly enough that the teeth of the pliers can successfully maintain a grip that does not slip off the stem.  Practice and intuition will take you through this successfully.   By using the curved head of the ViceGrip pliers in a rolling motion, not unlike the curve of claw hammer head, with a gentle yet firm tugging motion, the nail stands a good chance of coming out.  Use of wedges, again, not unlike you would with a clawhammer head, will help as well.  The object is to place enough of a pulling force on the nail stem, without causing it to sheer off in the process of removing it from the wood.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a couple of other options to the list.

- For nail heads not completely embedded in the wood, you can use carpenter's pincers.

[image]

You work the jaws to the bottom of the nail head, then squeezing the handles provides the leverage to get the jaws under the head.  From there, you can easily lever the nail out enough to pull it with a bigger tool, cut it off, or reposition the pincer to pull it out.  Some pincers have a hardened head and allow you to cut softer nails if you have a lot of hand strength.

[image]

- Another approach if you do this a lot and have an air compressor, is to use a pneumatic nail remover.  They aren't necessarily expensive.  One of the first ones I spotted on Amazon was under $50, and I wouldn't be surprised if Harbor Freight has a $20 version.  :-)

[image]

You use this to remove nails after pulling the boards apart.  You slide the snout over the protruding nail (may need to straighten the nail if its bent over).  A ram knocks the nail back out of the wood.  Here's a video that shows it in use starting at 3:00 minutes in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEejvcNBoCg

A clever guy made a manual version with an impact driver bit holder.  Here's a video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWeEbYYySLw   The video is way longer than it needs to be.  The relevant part starts a minute into the video, and how to use it starts at 3:30 (you can figure out the first part if you watch starting at 3:30).

Answer (score -1):

Use 2 strong planks + 2 strong supporting planks like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWnj4fUhyjI

Comment: -1 Link only answers become useless when the link goes bad and are frequently confused with spam. Be sure to provide context around the link and quote relevant content in case the link goes bad. See [how to answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.